# Handling all routes except subdomain in express-subdomain

Tags: javascript, express, subdomain, router, express-subdomain

I'm using [express-subdomain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain) for handling subdomains of my site.

I have these two: `www.mysite.com` and `blog.mysite.com` and I want to handle their corresponding requests separately so that they don't have access to each other's routers.

```
//index.js
app.use(subdomain("blog", blogRouter)); // Handle all requests from the blog
app.use("/api", mainRouter);            // Handle all requests from the main site
```

They both work, but the problem is when I'm in my blog and I run `blog.mysite.com/api` I still have access to the `/api` response of the main site. How can I prevent it?

Also, the `mainRouter` looks like this:

```
// mainRouter.js
const router = express.Router();

router.use("/some-path", somePathHandler);
router.use("/some-other-path", someOtherPathHandler);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Are you using nginx to host the site?

Comment: @SwapnilSoni no, I'm using heroku to host the site